# Stream file from S3 in lambda does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, lambda, aws-lambda

I want to load a file from S3 with line seperated values and push it into an array.

The following code does work on my local machine, but does not work executed as a lambda function. The lambda function times out (even if I bump the timeout up to 15 seconds). 
Are the SDK's different? What do I miss here since I get no error message at all beside the timeout?

Lambda Env: Node 6.10
Permission to access S3 is set like this

```
"Statement": [{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "s3:*"
  ],
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket",
    "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
  ]
}]
```

Code looks like this

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3({region:'eu-central-1'});

exports.index = function(event, context, callback){
  var params = {
  Bucket: 'mybucket',
  Key: 'file.txt'
}

urls=[];

var stream = s3.getObject(params);

stream.on('httpError',function(err){
  console.log(err);
  throw err;
});

stream.on('httpData', function(chunk) {
  urls.push(chunk.toString());
});

stream.on('httpDone', function() {
  urls2 = urls.join('\n\r');
  callback(urls2);
});

stream.send();

}
```

I got following error executing the lambda via AWS console

```
{
  "errorMessage": "2017-07-04T18:25:20.271Z 19ab7138-60e6-11e7-9e1e-c318d929bc39 Task timed out after 15.00 seconds"
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: lambda function requires event to trigger the script. On what event are you triggering the script?

Comment: sure, I manually execute the lambda via 'Test'-Button from Console at the moment. The execution starts, but it looks like none of the events were hit... so callback() gets never called and the lambda times out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works as expected Thanks at @anand for verifing it. 
The issue was related to VPC settings. 
Unfortunatly a good proper error message would have helped. But at the end of the day lesson learned.
If you are running on a VPC and your lambda code should run but you get a time out, better check your security and network settings =)

Comment: Can you give more info as to what was wrong with the network/security settings? I assume S3 was setup to not be publicly accessible, but am curious on what updates you did to make your stuff work.

Answer (score 0):

Handler is required to invoke the lambda function. Also, you need to mention handler name in the lambda function configuration.

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
  const key = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
  const params = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: key,
  };
  var stream = s3.getObject(params);
  ....
  stream.send();
}
```

`eports.handler` is invoked when lambda function triggers. Make sure you must define the handler name(`filename.handler`) in lambda function configuration.

If you trigger this code on s3 file upload it will read the uploaded s3 file. you change the bucket & key name to read any file(which exist).
Follow the documentation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html

Comment: Thx for your reply. The lambda gets executed as mentioned above. I can run it via AWS console. The events get never hit. =/ .. (edited the post, sry)

Comment: change the bucket & key name because export.handler won't pass the values if the lambda function is not triggered via s3 put or post. instead, use the fixed value.

Comment: use const params = {
  Bucket: 'mybucket',
  Key: 'file.txt'
}  
and make sure lambda function has permission to read s3 bucket.

Comment: yes, I did as you can see in my post. I also posted the permissions, do I miss some there?

Comment: are you using any node module? if you are then you need to zip all the code with dependencies and then upload